# Select “Storage Blob Data Contributor” role to Azure storage account and assign access to the new app registration created using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions

Select “Storage Blob Data Contributor” role to Azure storage account and  “Assign access to” as “User, group or service principal” to the app created. How to write same using terraform?

```
 resource azurerm_role_assignment example_role_assignment {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.main.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Owner"
  principal_id         = azuread_application.main[0].application_id
}
```

What should be pricipal id here? I think it should be app objectId but how to bring that in scope of storage account. not very familiar with terraform

Comment: can someone help